# AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, httpresponse

I'm currently building out some unit tests for my django application, however my test_views test keeps returning an error when run, and I'm unsure as to what it means and how to resolve it.

This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\t-dalour\app\blog\requests\unit tests\test_views.py", line 15, in test_user_can_register_successfully
    self.assertEqual(res.data['email'], self.user_data['email'])
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

And this is my test_views.py code:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from requests.models import Post
from .test_setup import TestSetUp


class TestViews(TestSetUp):
    def test_user_cannot_register_with_no_data(self):
        res=self.client.post(self.register_url)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)

    def test_user_can_register_successfully(self):
        res=self.client.post(
            self.register_url, self.user_data, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(res.data['email'], self.user_data['email'])
        self.assertEqual(res.data['username'], self.user_data['username'])
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
```

I've tried searching the internet for a solution to the error, but can't find anything relating to it. I'm assuming it's related to the 'res.data' part?
If anyone could help with how I could fix this it would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

when test with using django test client, you can easily access response data

I hope you read this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either read `context` or if it's `DRF`/`api-type view` call the `.json()` method of `response`.

For example:

```py
    def test_json_response(self):  # noqa: D102
        response = self.client.post(
            self.url,
            {},
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        data = response.json()
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpResponse objects have no data attribute whatsoever, Response objects (which belong to the DRF package AFAIK) do. Not sure why you expect a Response object, but in your case, you should access your content like this:

```
data = res.content
```

Notice this will return a string, so if you expect some json content, you will probably need to parse it.